# constrain random points with a polygon in R using sp library

Tags: r, point-in-polygon, sp

I have a map of London's waterways, which I've grided into a raster dataset to enable me to measure proximity to water from randomly generated points.

What I'd like to do please is to constrain the randomly generated points to a polygon (which represents the sampling area) within  the larger grid.

This is the code I've used:

```
randLocs <- spsample(waterGrid, n=200, type='random')
```

waterGrid is the overall grid enabling me to measure distances, and I have a polygon which I've loaded as a shapefile.

Comment: Put the polygon in as the first argument to spsample rather than the grid.

Comment: Thanks very much. I've put poly as the first argument: randVals <- spsample(poly,waterGrid,n=606,type="random") but get error message: Error in apply(bb, 1, function(x) diff(range(x))) : dim(X) must have a positive length. Could there be any other possible options? Many thanks

Comment: maybe try `spsample(poly,n=606,type="random")`?

Answer (score 1):

selecting your `randLocs` points that intersect with `poly` is done by

```
randLocs[poly, ]
```